# How to get multiple to One Relation in Oracle Sql Query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have product code defined in a table A where i will list 3 products with quantity. If customer purchase those 3 items I will be offering 1 product free.

### Product Code

1. Item A
2. Item B
3. Item C

For these items I will be offering "Item D" as free.

How do I write a query to check, whether all the 3 items are available in current table?

Comment: Please add your table structure in the question.

Comment: How about you at least show some effort? SO is not a free service code. Please add your attempt in solve your own problem.

Comment: mention a little about the structure of your table and o/p expected.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you aren’t giving us enough information to go ahead and help you. From what you said this is what I am thinking. You have a table such as this:

[image: FIGURE 1: TABLE]

You want a select that checks if all 3 items are available in the current table:

> **SELECT** CASE WHEN COUNT (PRODUCT_CODE) = 3 THEN
>
> ```
>   'YOU GET FREE ITEM D'
>  ELSE
>
>   'YOU DONT GET ANYTHING'
>
>  END AS ANSWER
> ```
>
> **FROM** TABLE_A
>
> **WHERE** (PRODUCT_CODE = *PRODUCT_CODE_1* **AND** QUANTITY > 0)
>
> **OR** (PRODUCT_CODE = *PRODUCT_CODE_2* **AND** QUANTITY > 0)
>
> **OR** (PRODUCT_CODE = *PRODUCT_CODE_3* **AND** QUANTITY > 0)

So basically the where clause is check if those 3 items exists and there quantity is greater than zero. Then I wrote a Case statement (you can use decode if you prefer) to check if the count is 3 then give me my free item else don’t give me.